# android.os.DeadObjectException at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)

Tags: android

I am aware about the generic explanation of `DeadObjectException` and I have gone through all the related links. How to handle this exception?

```
InputMethodManagerService: Session failed to close due to remote exception android.os.DeadObjectException
at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:504)
at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodSession$Stub$Proxy.finishSession(IInputMethodSession.java:305)
at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.finishSessionLocked(InputMethodManagerService.java:1474)
at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.clearClientSessionLocked(InputMethodManagerService.java:1465)
at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.clearCurMethodLocked(InputMethodManagerService.java:1491)
at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.onServiceDisconnected(InputMethodManagerService.java:1510)
at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doDeath(LoadedApk.java:1254)
at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1268)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:342)
at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:223)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:956)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:751)
```